# Bin date values by month from imported CSV in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a `.csv` file with the following example schema:

```
item, date
10,2015.01.01
2,2015.02.01
3,2015.01.15
4,2015.03.01
5,2015.03.01
20,2015.03.01
11,2015.02.01
23,2015.01.21
13,2015.01.31
```

I'm looking to bin the items into year/month/days i.e. `2015-01, 2015-02, 2015-03`.
I tried the following line by it doesn't seem to work:

```
select item by 1 xbar date.month from table
```

Also tried updating with a new column:

```
update column: `mm$date from table
```

It seems that importing the `.csv` file casts the fields to a symbols. Do i need to explicitly cast this back to a date type first?

How can i print out a table with values binned by a certain time/date criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply types when reading in a csv, use `0:` as follows:

```
q)("ID";enlist ",") 0: `:test.csv
item date
---------------
10   2015.01.01
2    2015.02.01
3    2015.01.15
4    2015.03.01
5    2015.03.01
20   2015.03.01
11   2015.02.01
23   2015.01.21
13   2015.01.31
```

The left argument is a two item list, the `"ID"` specifies the type of each column (integer, date) and the `","` specifies the separator (and the `enlist` indicates column headers are present).

Then the data can be bucketed by month:

```
q)select item by 1 xbar `month$date from ("ID";enlist ",") 0: `:test.csv
date   | item
-------| -----------
2015.01| 10 3 23 13i
2015.02| 2 11i
2015.03| 4 5 20i
```

Alternatively, if you want to have buckets of custom size, you can use `bin` with a list of dates as bucket dividers. This will give an integer value indicating which bin each date falls, then you can use a dictionary to name the buckets:

```
q)b:2015.01.01 2015.02.01 2015.03.01
q)d:(0 1 2)!`month$b
q)select item by d b bin date from ("ID";enlist ",") 0: `:test.csv
date   | item
-------| -----------
2015.01| 10 3 23 13i
2015.02| 2 11i
2015.03| 4 5 20i
```

Note: `bin` will assign `-1` for values below the first divider. Using `binr` will start counting at `0`:

```
q)b bin 2014.12.31
-1
q)b binr 2014.12.31
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the syntax you provided alongside a `value` keyword i.e. ```binByMonth: {value "select distinct ",x," by 1 xbar 'month$date from sample"}```. The values "x" that are printed have a comma in-front of the symbols i.e. ```,'OP```, is there a way to make this a string?

Comment: The ```,`OP``` indicate a list containing one item, the symbol ```OP```. To make this a string use `first` to extract the first (and only) element of the list then `string` to convert it to a string. So ```{string first x}``` as a function. However, if you want to select columns dynamically, a functional select might suit your needs better.